# how to access json data in processing.js

Tags: javascript, json, processing.js

I am trying to access json data which is there inside data folder inside my project folder. But I am getting "Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to execute pjs sketch: ReferenceError: loadJSONArray is not defined" error.

The JSON Data is as follows:

```
[
    {
       "month": "january", 
       "total": 32393, 
       "disease": 2761, 
       "wounds": 83, 
       "other": 324
    },
    {
       "month": "february", 
       "total": 30919, 
       "disease": 2120, 
       "wounds":  42, 
       "other": 361
    }
]
```

This is my HTML file and I am using processing version 1.3.6.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="processing-1.3.6.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="demo.pde"></canvas>    
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my processing code. (demo.pde)

```
JSONArray values;

void setup() {
size(800,600);
background(255);
noLoop();

values = loadJSONArray("data/data.json");

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject deads = values.getJSONObject(i); 
    int total = deads.getInt("total");
    String month = deads.getString("month");
    println(total + ", " + month);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to install [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/), you can easily call methods such as `$.ajax({})` or more specifically `$.getJson({})` whereby you can loop through your results with `$.each`.

Example given in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) documentation:

```
$.getJSON( "data/data.json", function( data ) {

  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
   // YOUR CODE
   // example: 
   var result = val.total + ' ' + val.month;
  });

});
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a quick [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/0h16tmzy/2/) showing how to use the `$.each()`

Comment: I am not able to understand how should I add this to my demo.pde file?since I want to code using processing.js

Answer (score 0):

Processing.js does not have support for loadJSONArray yet, plus all data requests are asynchronous in JavaScript, so loadJSONArray can't work the way the Processing API makes it work right now.

You can simply load the values in plain JS context, and then feed them into your sketch (following http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html or the like)