# loasJSONArray is not defined in Processing.Js

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I've made a processing program which work nicely. So I wanted to put it on my website with processing.js. I've used the code in their demo to load my pde file:

```
  script(src='/javascripts/lib/processing.min.js')
  canvas(data-processing-sources="processing/paris_tree_viz.pde")
```

But when I launch my page, I got the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: loadJSONArray is not defined

Here is my setup void in my processing pde file, which contains the loadJSONArray method:

```
void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
  background(255, 255, 255, 1);
  colorMode(RGB);

  data = loadJSONArray("http://opendata.paris.fr/explore/dataset/les-arbres/download/?format=json&timezone=Europe/Berlin");
  trees = filterBySpecie(data);
}
```

How can I make my program work properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access json data in processing.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630004/how-to-access-json-data-in-processing-js)

Answer (score 0):

Googling your error got me to this duplicate: [how to access json data in processing.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630004/how-to-access-json-data-in-processing-js)

According to that duplicate, Processing.js does not have a loadJSONArray function. And the Processing.js reference seems to confirm this: http://processingjs.org/reference/

That suggest that you're running your sketch in Java mode. Don't do that- switch to JavaScript mode, so that you can catch errors like this before you deploy.

The solution seems to be to load the Strings yourself, or to load the JSON from JavaScript and pass them into your sketch.